# Laravel Fatal Error memory but memory_limit set to 2048MB

Tags: php, linux, laravel

I have just set up a new Laravel 8 project. When i try and run it i get the following fatal error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 2097152 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 32768 bytes) in /media/cal/500GB/cal/backend/vendor/composer/autoload_static.php on line 2297
```

PHP memory_limit is set to 2048MB

if I try and run any command related to Laravel or Composer I get a fatal error so this command

```
laravel --version
```

gives me this error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 2097152 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 12288 bytes) in /home/cal/.config/composer/vendor/symfony/console/Color.php on line 165
```

Even just typing composer give me the memory_error.

This command shows I have 2048MB memory_limit

```
php -r "echo ini_get('memory_limit').PHP_EOL;"
```

Where does composer get that value of just 2MB from?

How can I fix this please? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Where are you stuck? Does the code set another memory limit anywhere?

Comment: You might have different `php.ini` files for CLI and web. And therefore you "think" you changed the limit, but it only applies to CLI and not web.

Comment: @NicoHaase I have searched the system for any php.ini files and i found 2. One in /etc/php/7.4/cli and the other in /etc/php/7.4/apache2 and I set the memory_limit on both to 2048MB. I honestly have no idea if Laravel or Composer sets the limit somewhere else this is all new to me.

Comment: Try to use `2048M` - the configuration does not use a `B` at the end

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If  `php -r "echo ini_get('memory_limit').PHP_EOL;"` prints a setting of `2048MB`, you mis-configured the memory limit. According to the documentation, it should **not** contain a `B` at the end. Try to set it to `2048M` instead

Comment: Only thing that doesn't make sense is why does it say 2MB of memory was exhausted when the memory limit was set to 128MB?

Comment: Did you set it to `128MB`? Then you are facing the same problem, as there should **not** be a `B` in the end

Comment: No I never touched it and it gave me that error with the default settings, which is why i am so confused. But it works now so all good thanks for your help!